# How to disable the built-in RAID in x3650 M3?

Tags: ibm-xseries, ibm, megaraid

We have an IBM server x3650 M3, and I'm trying to install Linux without using HW RAID (ServeRAID), as per cluster storage software vendor requirements.

The problem is that the server exposes the physical drives only to WebBios interface, and Linux insallation (RedHat Anakonda) sees only the virtual drives, not the physical ones. If we clear the RAID configuration, the installation doesn't see any drives at all.

Is there any way to disable the built-in ServeRaid and expose the drives to operation system?

Or the only way is to bypass RAID physically and connect the disks to motherboard directly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I needed to set up a software RAID on x3850. The only thing, helped me is configuring every disk as a separate volume in RAID configuration utility (I think this is nearly what you call "WebBios")

Comment: Hi. Do you remember what exact option you used to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Also, was there any performance hit as the result?

Comment: I can't have a look at the menu at the moment, but I remember that I selected "create new array", then selected only one drive. After this the only option was to create "Volume". Alas I didn't compare the performance between RAID and separate disks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it out by creating a volume per every disk - not a clean solution, but seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

try turn off raid bios in ur main BIOS.

Comment: Where exactly? We looking through BIOS and didn't find any such option.

Comment: usualy in pci-devices.